# GRE-level reading materials

Tags: reading

I am preparing for the GRE-reading part. I am told that Guardian, Economist LA times are good reading sources. But the thing is they all cost a lot to subscribe. Is there free reading materials online that are comparable to those of reading levels? Thanks.

Comment: The UK _Guardian_ website is free to use.

Comment: Some major newspapers and journals are providing  their coronavirus coverage free. And it includes not only health but politics, economics, international affairs—as well as health. More than you need on epidemiology, but you can focus on the more general stuff. Meanwhile, this is off-topic.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it’s general reference.

Comment: @Beacon, do some research, instead of relying on what you are "told". At least one of the sites you say "cost a lot" is actually free to use.

Comment: The Guardian not only has a lot of balanced, well-written journalism, opinion, and informative material, but one of the best [style guides](https://www.theguardian.com/guardian-observer-style-guide-a) - and all free (of course, you can choose to contribute).